# Making background slide animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a button group, and want when user select each button background of previous or next button move/slide to selected one, i made this effect with pure `css` and just used `jquery` to add or remove `active` class. now the problem is when you click on `All` button, then `New` it works fine, but if you click on `Used` the slide not work in right position.

For this effect i used `transition` and `::before`, need to solve this with pure `css` or minimum jquery, not a lot of `javascript` or `jquery` codes.

The logic to move this background is:

```
.RadioButton .btn:first-child::before {
 right: 0;
 transition: .3s all ease;
}

.RadioButton .btn:nth-child(2)::before {
 transition: .3s all ease;
}

.RadioButton .btn:last-child::before {
  left: 0;
  transition: .3s all ease;
}
```

The problem on `.RadioButton .btn:nth-child(2)::before` i can't use `right:0` or `left:0` because if i use each one, the slide effect not work in right position, any solution?

What i tried so far:

```js
$('.RadioButton').each(function(){
 $(this).find('.btn').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
   $(this).parent().find('.btn').removeClass('btn-active');
   $(this).addClass('btn-active');
  });
 });
});
```

```css
body {
direction: rtl;
}

.RadioButton .btn {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 11px;
    min-height: 30px!important;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-default {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    color: gray;
}

.btn-group>.btn:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group>.btn:nth-child(2) {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group>.btn:last-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.RadioButton .btn::before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    background: gray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: .3s all ease;
    z-index: -1;
}

.btn-active::before {
    width: 100%!important;
}

.RadioButton .btn:nth-child(2)::before {
 right: 0;
 transition: .3s all ease;
}

.RadioButton .btn:last-child::before {
  left: 0;
  transition: .3s all ease;
}

.btn-active:first-child::before {
 left: 0;
 transition: .3s all ease;
}

.btn-active:last-child::before {
  left: 0;
  transition: .3s all ease;
}

.btn.btn-default.btn-active {
    color: white;
}

.btn-group {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="RadioButton btn-group" id="searchType">
 <a class="btn btn-default" data-val="0">Used</a>
 <a class="btn btn-default" data-val="1">New</a>
 <a class="btn btn-default btn-active" data-val="2">All</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set only one after pseudo, on the last button.
Now, use sibbling selectors and the active class to move it to the left, as appropiate. (see the last 2 styles in the CSS)

```js
$('.RadioButton').each(function(){
 $(this).find('.btn').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
   $(this).parent().find('.btn').removeClass('btn-active');
   $(this).addClass('btn-active');
  });
 });
});
```

```css
body {
direction: rtl;
}

.RadioButton .btn {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 11px;
    min-height: 30px!important;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-default {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    color: gray;
}

.btn-group>.btn:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group>.btn:nth-child(2) {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group>.btn:last-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.btn.btn-default.btn-active {
    color: white;
}

.btn-group {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.RadioButton .btn:nth-child(3)::before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: gray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: .3s all ease;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 0px;
}

.btn-active:first-child ~ .btn::before {
    transform: translateX(calc(-4px - 200%));
}
.btn-active:nth-child(2) ~ .btn::before {
    transform: translateX(calc(-2px - 100%));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="RadioButton btn-group" id="searchType">
 <a class="btn btn-default" data-val="0">Used</a>
 <a class="btn btn-default" data-val="1">New</a>
 <a class="btn btn-default btn-active" data-val="2">All</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

change position center

```js
$('.RadioButton').each(function(){
 $(this).find('.btn').each(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
   $(this).parent().find('.btn').removeClass('btn-active');
   $(this).addClass('btn-active');
  });
 });
});
```

```css
body {
direction: rtl;
}

.RadioButton .btn {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 11px;
    min-height: 30px!important;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
}

.btn-default {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    color: gray;
}

.btn-group>.btn:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group>.btn:nth-child(2) {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.btn-group>.btn:last-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

.RadioButton .btn::before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 0%;
    background: gray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: .3s all ease;
    z-index: -1;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.btn-active::before {
    width: 100%!important;
}

.RadioButton .btn:nth-child(2)::before {
 
 transition: .3s all ease;
}

.RadioButton .btn:last-child::before {
  
  transition: .3s all ease;
}

.btn-active:first-child::before {
 
 transition: .3s all ease;
}

.btn-active:last-child::before {
  
  transition: .3s all ease;
}

.btn.btn-default.btn-active {
    color: white;
}

.btn-group {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="RadioButton btn-group" id="searchType">
 <a class="btn btn-default" data-val="0">Used</a>
 <a class="btn btn-default" data-val="1">New</a>
 <a class="btn btn-default btn-active" data-val="2">All</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The effect is not right, I want move background (with slide animation) to next or prev depend on which is clicked. (on my snippet, from right to left, click first button, then center, then left one). i want this effect.